# Chrome won't show my HTML 5 video on my windows Computer (I have Divx)

Tags: html, google-chrome, windows-7, html5-video, divx

I have the Divx plugin downloaded (i think) the html files play in all my other browers but chrome. Instead, all that shows up in chrome is a black box with the words Divx in them. Why?

Here is my HTML5 code:

```
<div class = "video-js-box">
  <video class = "video-js" width = "675" height = "380" controls>
    <source src = "/videos/videofiles/Reversing_a_Track.mp4"
           type = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';/>
    <source src = "/videos/videofiles/Reversing_a_Track.ogg"
           type = 'video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
    <source src = "/videos/videofiles/Reversing_a_Track.webm"
           type = 'video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this solution:
http://codecanyon.net/forums/thread/divx-vs-html5-in-chrome/61708