# Why is Google Chrome not loading my video?

Tags: html, google-chrome, movie

I have created 3 versions of a video file using Miro Video Converter to facilitate different browsers and I am using the following code to play them...

```
               <video class="rw-video video-js" data-settings="rw-green rw-flat-color rw-rounded"  title="My movie title" preload="auto" controls width="800" height="400" id="exampleVid1" poster="images/video.png" >
                <source src="images/movie1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                <source src="images/movie1.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
                <source src="images/movie1.webm" type="video/webm" />
                <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
                </video>
```

The video plays just fine in firefox and safari but not in chrome - it appears to play in chrome but never starts - the hourglass just goes round and round and it never plays. I have checked filenames and that the video is uploaded.  Any ideas? I wondered if Chrome maybe interprets "preload="auto"" to mean preload the entire video but fiddling with that didnt make any difference I could see. The movies are around 50mb in total and load instantly in other browsers.

Comment: Anything in error console?

Comment: No, nothing. Which of the three formats will Chrome be trying to play?

Comment: Under "network" in the inspector there is an error actually in red saying "cancelled" next to MP4 "video.html:144 parser"

Comment: "144 parser" links to the last empty line of my html file after the closing </html>

Comment: Can you try to access the mp4 file directly using the url? can you test it with any other mp4 files? Something not encoded with the same software maybe?

Comment: yeah when I play it locally plays fine even in chrome - through the browser remotely it wont even play with a direct url - just says divx crashed.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017859/chrome-wont-show-my-html-5-video-on-my-windows-computer-i-have-divx

Answer (score 0):

this is actually a Google Chrome bug which prevents it to load more than 6 MP4 videos. Try putting `preload="none"` on all the videos and then start clicking on them. You will probably be able to open 6 of them but on 7th video Google Chrome will hang. That is how it is with me, but maybee this will happen sooner on your system.

But you will trigger the bug if you have MP$ video among your videos, so it is best to completely avoid the MP4 format. I solved it completely by using webm video format.